# Reading file into char array in C: Or how to dynamically allocate an array?

Tags: c, arrays, buffer, system-calls

Using Linux system calls **open** and **read**. The **read** call accepts 3 parameters

```
read(File descriptor, Buffer array, Size of the buffer array);
```

My question is related to the argument #3. Suppose I have multiple text files that I want to read into my buffer array. But as far as I know C doesn't have something like *Vector* or *ArrayList* or any other structure with a dynamic size.

Is there an easy way to calculate the size of the file so I know how much space should I allocate for my char array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also `stat()` the file to determine its size and then call [mmap()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on it.  Your file will appear as an "array" without the need to `malloc()` memory.

Comment: I would probably avoid trying to equate arrays and pointers, even if only to make matters simple.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're on linux you can use [`stat(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) to get the file size. The structure `stat` contains a field `st_size` which indicates the total size in bytes.

---

Is reading the entire file in memory really the best way to go ?

Comment: Is `off_t` safely converted to `size_t`?

Comment: @oldrinb Not sure :-? Don't think so

Comment: I was just curious, since `malloc` takes `size_t`.

Comment: @oldrinb Yup, one has to check sizes.

Comment: @cnicutar since the compiler sees the declaration of malloc, it can perform an implicit integer-to-integer cast. Also, stat() isn't Linux-only - it's POSIX.

Comment: @H2CO3, that doesn't mean it's safe. If `OFF_MAX` is the maximum value for `off_t` and `SIZE_MAX < OFF_MAX` were true, such an implicit conversion (not a cast) could be very unsafe, indeed.

Comment: @eq- yes, but it still doesn't forbid the implicit cast to happen, just there may be an integer overflow.

Comment: @H2CO3, (there is no such thing as an implicit cast), I think the original question was whether the conversion is safe (or done safely), not whether it will be implicit.

Comment: @eq- "there's no such thing as an implicit cast" I just read it up and it's called an implicit conversion indeed (cast = explicit conversion) - although I'm sure you just wanted to badger me, please don't.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it qualifies as efficient, but it is "easy" to simply move to the end of the file and grab the length from there:

```
    fseek(readf, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(readf);
    buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen);
```

Comment: `ftell` returns `long int`; is that safely convertible to `size_t`?

Comment: @oldrinb see my other comment on it. Basically, don't worry about all these integral types...

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not particularly worried about whether the cast will occur... it's the fact that the cast might return something surprising :-)

Comment: @oldrinb that's a reasonable fear :) Though see Mike's explanation.

Comment: @oldrinb - As I understand it, a size_t is (according to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), an unsigned integer). On a 32-bit system, I believe a long int is 2^31-1 and unsigned int is 2^32-1, so it should be safe. Unless my math is off.

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice is to read into a fixed length buffer, then copy each "record" into a dynamically allocated structure (e.g. malloc() a struct* or a char*).

As cnicutar suggested, you can also "stat" the file, malloc() a buffer that size, and read the file all at once.